# Lightning component : displaying some text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html5

In a lightning component I display some text dynamically, from the field "Description" of a customized object "Article__c".
So when in salesforce I fill the Description field, it appears in my component.

The problem is when, in Salesforce, I put a line break in the Description fiels, in my component I see "`<br>`"

Is there any way to fix that ?

In the developper console I saw that `<br>` is not approved, it has to be `<br/>` but salsforce automatically create the `<br>` tag...

here is a bit of my code:

```
<aura:component controller="ActuliteImageController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="art" type="Article__c[]"/>

<div class="conteneur">
<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.art}">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="texte">{!a.Name} : <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!a.Description__c}"/></div>
        <p><img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.image.Id}" /></p>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
</div>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: the answer `<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.note.body}"/>` could have worked, but not... I still see the tag `<br>`, or I don't put the code at the right place...

Comment: if you can share your current code, that will help some one to answer you.

Comment: I edited my question with the aura:unescapedHtml at the right place, and it's working, if it can help someone...